# Select the 5 sport disciplines in which there is the less sport event

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have this Sports table :

```
CREATE TABLE Sports(
    name_sport VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    categories_sport VARCHAR(50),
    type_result_sport VARCHAR(50),
    discipline TEXT,
    enEquipe BOOLEAN 
);
```

That I filled with data like :

```
('Women''s 50m Freestyle','freestyle','aquatics','temps','FALSE'),

('Trap Women','shooting','shooting','temps','FALSE'),
('10m Air Pistol Men','shooting','shooting','score','FALSE'),
('10m Air Rifle Men','shooting','shooting','score','FALSE'),

('Women''s Discus Throw','throws','athletics','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s Hammer Throw','throws','athletics','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s Javelin Throw','throws','athletics','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 100m','track','athletics','temps','FALSE'),

('Women''s Doubles','badminton','badminton','temps','TRUE'),
('Women''s Singles','badminton','badminton','temps','FALSE'),
('Men''s Doubles','badminton','badminton','temps','TRUE'),
('Men''s Singles','badminton','badminton','temps','FALSE'),

('Lightweight Women''s Double Sculls','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Women''s Double Sculls','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Women''s Eight','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Women''s Pair','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Women''s Quadruple Sculls','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Women''s Single Sculls','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Lightweight Men''s Double Sculls','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'),
('Lightweight Men''s Four','rowing','rowing','temps','FALSE'), 

('Women''s +75kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 48kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 53kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 58kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 63kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 69kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Women''s 75kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s +105kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 105kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 56kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 62kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 69kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 77kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 85kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
('Men''s 94kg','weightlifting','weightlifting','score','FALSE'),
```

I'm trying to select the 5 categories (aquatics, athletics, archery ...) which have the less sport event (Men's 100m, Women's 50m Freestyle ...)

In this case, the output would be :

```
Aquatics
Athletics
Shooting
badminton
rowing
```

Thanks

EDIT 1 : Added more sample data and output wanted.

Comment: Can you share some (more) sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample? It would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this. group by statement groups categories, order by orders results by number of occurances on each category, and limit limits the number of returning results to 5

```
 select categories_sport, count(*) as cnt
   from Sports
  group by (categories_sport)
  order by cnt asc
  limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an aggregated query with a `GROUP BY categories_sport`, sorted by ascending count, and with a `LIMIT` clause on to 5 results.

This will work in both mysql and postgres (you tagged both) :

```
SELECT categories_sport, count(*)
FROM sports
GROUP BY categories_sport
ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: dont't you see that you are giving exacly answer with me :) how odd!!

Comment: Hello @Simonare, well I guess the answer is obvious enough that we both came up with the same answer...